# How to data bind the text property of a TextBlock to the text property of a TextBox

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a WPF application with two pages.  On page one, there is a TextBox (boxSource).  On page two, I have a TextBlock (blockDestination).  I want to databind in XAML, the Text property of boxSource to the Text property of blockDestination.

I set the DataContext of page two to page one when the application is initialized.  I setup blockDestination as follows:

```
<TextBlock Name="blockDestination" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding boxSource, Path=Text, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

This does not pickup the value of the TextBox.  My guess is that it is because the TextBox is a variable instead of a property?

Can anyone explain the issue, and is there an elegant solution?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that XAML to work, your "page one" will need to be set as the data context of page two, with the boxSource variable defined as a property, so that in the setter, you can raise the PropertyChanged event.

Matthias is right, though, this is a pretty brittle way to implement this, and one of the places where an MVVM approach will be more robust in the long run.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.  I agree that the MVVM approach is better, but this was just a very small, limited use application, so I was trying to cut corners.  Probably still a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

An elegant solution would be to define a View Model common to all pages. You should always bind to properties of the view model and should avoid binding to UI Elements. Using a view model you can always access all neccessary values and define several presentations in different pages.

I've read something about pages having their own object space, so that UI elements can have the same name in different pages. Also it can happen that the first page isn't available after loading the second one. The binding target would then be unavailable.

Comment: It does exist, and can be accessed.  I see your point about the View Model; I agree, that would be a better solution over all.  I am still curious about the binding behavior though.

Comment: You can enable the debug output of a wpf application so that binding exceptions will be printed to the console (The output window in Visual Studio). Perhaps this helps.